# Is it possible to skip the last destination of an international flight?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I purchased a ticket from Europe to Brazil for this year. My itinerary was initially Amsterdam-Madrid-Sao Paolo consisting of two flights with the same airline. And a third domestic flight in Brazil, from Sao- Paolo to Belo Horizonte with another airline, a brazilian one which is not part of the alliance with the one I coming from Europe (I am not sure if my ticket is code sharing or just a combination flight to reach Belo Horizonte). 
The ticket was purchased from a travel website which has good offers for flight tickets.

Until recently everything was ok but now I do not want to go to Belo Horizonte and my question will be if I will stick only to Sao Paolo and ignore the local flight will my entire return ticket from Brazil to Europe will be cancelled or it will only be the domestic flight with the brazilian airline?

Comment: Just because the domestic airline is not part of the alliance, it could have a partnership with the international carrier and thus missing your domestic connection will be reported back to the originating carrier.  Do you have one PNR for AMS to CNF, or two PNRs one AMS to VCP and the other VCP to CNF?

Comment: Also, do you plan to check-in any bags?

Comment: Is this on the outbound, or the return leg?

Comment: @Gagravarr - outbound obviously from his post "will my entire return ticket from Brazil to Europe will be cancelled"

Comment: @AyeshK OP would have to collect his bags in GRU anyway for a Brazilian customs inspection

Comment: @ Yes I have two PNRs, one for AMS-GRU and the other one for GRU-CNF.  Does this will make a difference?

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert on such matters, but I have read many answers to this sort of question. This can be summarised as:

- IF the return ticket was booked as a single trip you MAY have the whole balance cancelled.
- Given the scenario you decribe there are probably too many possibilities to be sure of what the outcome will be without actually asking.

The travel website MAY be able to advise you, but such sites MAY not offer much support and, unless you can get their "opinion" in writing you'd have no defence if they turned out to be wrong (and even then that may not work).

In such a case I would personally seek written confirmation from somebody in the "link" whose answer should be binding. You could start by doing this anonymously - and may get success without having to give them details of the actual flights involved. In some cases, adding the domestic link may have made the overall journey cheaper (quite common) and removing it may increase the cost. If you started with the local airline they may be obliging - they are probably making money from the change.

Not giving your ID while you establish options is wise, if achievable, without casuing additional problems  - this is neither dishonest nor against the rules - I have had experiences in life where asking people about options, or lack of them, has triggered circumstances which were counterproductive, regardless of my intentions.

---

**Related only:**

FWIW - on an "around the world" flight my daughter was scheduled to fly from Dublin to Munich but decided to instead fly Dublin-Amsterdam on another airline and rejoin the flight at Munich. Unaware of the consequences she inquired of Lufthansa in Dublin, was told that they would cancel her whole ticket if she did so and then not only did so (prior to her making the other flight) but also annotated the record with statements that it must not be reinstated. She being young and very charming managed to sort things out in due course in Munich. Lufthansa has lost several customers for life and hopefully a few more every time I tell this tale (regardless of what the rule book said).

On another occasion, QANTAS gave me a "free" flight Sydney-Brisbane when I missed a flight through no fault of my own but it was NOT linked to the main ticket  (NZ-China-Australia) and I was not aware of the consequences. I told them how wonderful QANTAS was and I was sure they could sort something out, and they did. Hopefully telling that gains them customers :-)

Comment: A round-the-world ticket is different because it is (usually) semi-flexible and "no-showing" is allowed for a small penalty fee. In this case your daughter simply managed to talk her way out of a penalty for making after-departure changes plus the no show penalty. That is quite different to re-instating a ticket that has been cancelled by the system because a segment was not flown.

Comment: @Calchas The Lufthansa man was quite adamant that the ticket would be cancelled and he wrote very directive comments on the file to the effect that it should not be reinstated. No mention was made of being able to do it at extra cost or of being able to do it at all. My daughter is intelligent and able to function well under stress and also (according to everyone qualified to comment) a pleasant and reasonable person almost without exception (better than me on all counts :-) ) , so I'm inclined to trust her version of events as liable to be reasonably accurate.

Comment: Your daughter is more likely to be reliable than the Lufthansa man, I fear: Star Alliance does not issue non-changeable RTW fares (to be fair maybe that has changed recently, I am not an expert on Star Alliance).

Answer (score 4):

If you miss one flight coupon in the ticket then, unless your ticket permits no-showing (unlikely unless it was very expensive) the remaining flights on the ticket will be cancelled.

There are exceptions, particularly when IT links between the airlines are poor, but that is what you agreed when you bought a discounted ticket.

If you want to change your itinerary then you should call the travel agent to make the change. A change before departure will be repriced using fares in effect today. A change after departure will be repriced using historical fares in effect at the time the ticket was first issued. Therefore, if you are very close to departure, it may be cheaper to make the change after you have flown the first flight on the ticket.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because this says the truth: The chances are very slim to use the remaining of the ticket if you missed a leg.

I spent a night in the airport and the local HQ of an airliner after missing my flight. Even if I bought a ticket to the connecting flight that was due later that day, they could not restore my ticket. Discount fairs come with such burdens to bear.